# JS Validation reports as empty after selecting date

Tags: php, jquery, validation, datepicker

I have a small bug in my code. When a user selects the date field, a calendar pops up and a date can be clicked but the validation gives an error as though empty.

If the user clicks a second time the error goes away or if they click submit, the form goes through fine, even though the error text is still displayed.

Would like to clean up this loose end but some of this code is not my own so haven't been able to locate the issue.

The form field and validate function are below and a working copy is on jsfiddle.

Form code is

```
<label class="control-label" for="date">Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-giant btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Validation statement is

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery("#date").validate({
expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
message: "Please select a date."
});
});
```

I've posted a working sample on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgledhill/NdHGH/1/embedded/result/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate after the input has changed. You are validating before the text arrives at the input. You can see this fiddle not giving the error: http://jsfiddle.net/NdHGH/4/

I also moved your onclick away from an inline onclick to make it easier to understand:

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery('#date').on('click',function(){
    GetDate(this);
  });
  jQuery("#date").on('change',function(){
    validate({
      expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
      message: "Please select a date."
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not seem to work. I did further checking and it doesn't show an error when submit with empty field. When I change the code, none of the validation for the other fields work. Thanks for having a look.